# How to assign background image of button to a variable using jquery css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to assign background image of button in a jquery variable with css.I have written code but it not work.

```
var cmp1;
var cmp2;

var bg = $("#mq3").css('background-image');
var bg1 = $("#mq6").css('background-image');
var bg2 = $("#mq9").css('background-image');

$(document).ready(function() {    
       $("#mq9").click(function() {
           //alert("Hello Welcome");
           if ($("#mq9").css("background-image") === bg2) {
               $("#mq9").css("background-image", "url('images/bkv.png')");

               cmp1 = $("#mq9").css('background-image');
               cmp2 = $("#mq3").css('background-image');
               cmp3 = $("#mq6").css('background-image');

               if (cmp1 === cmp3) {
                   alert("welcome mohit");
                   //setTimeout("window.open('Qtwo.html')",3000);
              }
          } else {
               $("#mq9").css("background-image", "url('images/cmst.png')");
               bg2 = $("#mq9").css('background-image');
          }
     });
});
```

Comment: Explain `I have written code but it not work.`

Comment: whatever you have written it should work. please explain the exact issue. Also please look for any console error.

Comment: when i compare background image of two button then it not work properly  .please help me

Answer (score 0):

Do Something like this

```
var imageUrl = 'abc.png'
$('myOjbect').css('background-image', 'url(' + imageUrl + ')');
```

Comment: I have added background image in my .css file.I want to assign background image in the variable of jquery file.                                                                                                                   background-image:url('images/cmst.png');           this is in my css file and i want it to assign it in a variable of jquery or javascript file.so that i can compare it.

Comment: @user3207529 you can see in my example i am passing url in json object

Comment: Keval Bhatt , variable should retrieve image form .css file.I asked u to retrieve image form .css file and assign that image to javascript variable.

Answer (score 0):

> As **hy_sultani** said you can pass **variable** or if you have more then
>   1  css attribute then you can pass json also.

see this example : http://jsfiddle.net/kevalbhatt18/m0b34h1z/2/

```
var test={
    "color":"red",
    "background-image":"url('../img/logo.png')"
}
$('button').css(test)
```

And in json if you dont want "" in key value then your json shoud look like below example.

**Note:** if you remove "" from key value then you have to follow camelcase

```
test={
    color:"red",
    backgroundImage:"url(../img/logo.png)"
}
```

Comment: @user3207529 please put your complete code in jsFillde so we can compare

Comment: @user3207529 i cant get it what you wrote. i think you have to compare ,so can  you tell me you want to compare url or jquery object ?

Comment: @user3207529 k get it what you want give me some time will update my fiddle

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {                                                            var bg = $("#mq3").css('background-image');                                       var bg2 = $("#mq9").css('background-image');$("#mq9").click(function() {              if ($("#mq9").css("background-image") === bg2) {
            $("#mq9").css("background-image", "url('images/bkv.png')");
           cmp1 = $("#mq9").css('background-image');
            cmp2= $("#mq3").css('background-image');
            if (cmp1===cmp2) {
                alert("welcome mohit");
             }
}
    });

Comment: i want to compare jquery object,please help me thanks in advance

Comment: @user3207529 see this may be it will help you http://jsfiddle.net/kevalbhatt18/m0b34h1z/3/

Comment: @user3207529 i created fiddle for code which is given in comment see this fiddle also http://jsfiddle.net/kevalbhatt18/m0b34h1z/3/